# Using AWK to determine how many lines contain a string

Tags: awk

I'm trying to use AWK to determine how many lines in a file contain a string.

```
BEGIN {RS=FS} 
{if ($0 ~ /ed/) n++}
END {print n}
```

Works fine as long as *ed* is preceded by white space no matter what follows it, such as ed or education, but if the line contains muted or fed, it doesn't register them. I thought /.*ed/ would correct this but no such luck.

Comment: `awk '/ed/{++n} END{print n}'`

Answer (score 3):

Or just use `grep` with the `-c` option to count occurrences:

```
grep -c ed file
4
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove  `BEGIN {RS=FS}` and you should be fine.

cat file

```
ed
education
not here
covered
fed
not here
```

```
awk '/ed/ {n++} END {print n}' file
4
```

`$0~/ed/` is the same `/ed/`. It will search the line and if any `ed` is found increment the counter.
So in my example, `4` `ed` are found.